# como implementar o jquery no php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

boa tarde minha duvida e a seguinte eu quero colocar um alert customizado do jquery confirm no código em php mas ele não roda já tentei de tudo já chamei os arquivos e nada se alguém puder ajudar agradeço

aqui esta meu código o trecho onde quero colocar o jquery esta dentro de um echo:

```
echo"<script>alert('Nenhum Resultado Encontrado'), window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
```

eu tentei usar assim:

```
                    echo"<script>$.alert({
    title: 'Alert!',
    content: 'Simple alert!',
    confirm: function(){
        alert('Confirmed!');
    }
});, window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou normal  o primeiro código, veja no seu devTool em `console` se aparece algum erro.

Comment: O php é linguagem executado no lado servidor e o javascript no lado cliente(navegador). Deveria utilizar ajax para isso.

Comment: vish nao sei usar ajax como q eu posso fazer isso deste jeito? poderia me explicar rray?

Comment: O uso de ajax parece não tem nada a ver com o caso..

Comment: Acho que ele quer apenas um dialogbox customizado... mas acho estrnho o uso de `$.alert` pois não existe nativamente. E também o fato de parsear um código estático no PHP, parece sem sentido ou desnecessário.

Comment: Caso queria um "alert customizado do jquery", deve procurar pelo método `dialog()`: http://jsfiddle.net/eraj2587/Pm5Fr/14/

Comment: gente eu ja achei um plugin jquery que faz o alert customizado eu testei ele usando somente o javascript ou melhor dizendo o jquery ele ta rodando esta aprecendo o alert bunitinha mas eu quero implementar isso em um echo em php e nao consigo e isso que eu quero nao quero dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde,

Editado:
Pelo que percebi você quer dar um alerta para o usuário que o que ele procurou não foi encontrado. Você deve ter uma página como www.lovedevelopment.com.br/vusca.php?q=0 ( q=0 sendo que não encontrou o resultado ). Neste caso vamos ver como ficaria em php.

```
<?php 
   //Analisando o caso com a URL ww.lovedevelopment.com.br/vusca.php?q=0
   //vamos primeiro colocar em uma variável o resultado
   $testa_minha_busca = $_GET['q'];
    //Depois vamos testar se o resultado veio igual a 0
   if ( $testa_minha_busca == 0 ) {
       //Se for encontrado vamos mandar um alerta 
       echo "<script>alert('Sua busca tá osso man!');</script>";
       // Em seguida vamos mandar ele para home e 3 segundos
       header( "refresh:3;url=home.php" ); 
}
?>
```

Vi que uma das dicas que deram para você foi usar AJAX. Vamos primeiro aos principios de uso desse "Desinfetante".

O que é ?
Método que abre uma janela para passar informações do client-side para o Server-side.

E quando eu uso isso ?
Quero guardar meu dados em um banco de dados mysql e tenho um arquivo que insere isso no banco um insert.php só que os dados estão vindo de um formulário client-side e não quero usar o POST do PHP.

Vamos a um exemplo em uma busca. Tenho um arquivo que chama check_de_busca.php e quero mas quero que a busca seja dinamica e sem reload, e os dados vem do javascript. E quando o resultado é nulo ele retorna o esse arquivo chama check_de_busca.php.

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      //Quando clicar na busca
    $('botao_buca').click(function() {
        //chama o AJAX
      $.ajax({
          //vamos postar
        type: "post",
        //Para o Arquivo abaixo
        url: "check_de_busca.php",
        //A variável do javascript que eu quero passar para o PHP é termo de busca
        data: "busca"+termo_de_busca,
        //Asynchrono
        async: true,
        //Se ele der sucesso da requisição e for 0 avisa os truta
        success: function(result) {
          if (result == 0) {
            alert('Sua busca tá osso man!');
          }
        },
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Apenas ajuste suas variáveis e Divs. E uma dica adicional de interface, se vai mandar um alerta ( http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/ ).

Obrigado,

Fico a disposição

Comment: deixa eu ver se eu intendi entao eu co coloca esse script onde esta meu codigo do alert no echo do php? e tambem nao estou intendendo esses url: alguma coisa data: alguma coisa poderia me explicar direitinho o que o seu codigo esta fazendo?

Comment: um experiente entende o que ele quis te passar.. mas também entende que não é algo adequado pois apenas deixa uma pessoa confusa ainda mais confusa..

Comment: Daniel, tem toda razão minha resposta foi baseada no meu dia-a-dia, peço desculpa leonardo. Editei a resposta de forma que  fique mais completa e com mais dicas. Estou trabalhando para aprender a responder aqui no Stackflow